# php how to equate date from database to current date

Tags: php, mysql

*i have this code that connects to the database (vtiger_leadscf) and it gets data from it. The only data I want to get is when the date from the database to equal to the current date. My code doesn't seem to work *

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "cvgcrm";
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$today_time = strtotime($today);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT fname, date, lname FROM vtiger_leadscf where date =   &today_time ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["fname"]. "" . $row["date"]. " " . $row["lname"]. "         <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `&today_time` is this supposed to be a special type of variable? that `&` is awfully far from `$`

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `where date =   &today_time` is obviously incorrect and am hoping it's not a typo.

- The `&` as I mentioned in comments, is awfully far from `$` on the keyboard.

The `&` should be a `$`, it's a [**variable**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

```
where date = $today_time
```

Now, if the value going in there is a string, it needs to be quoted.

```
where date = '$today_time'
```

Not doing so, MySQL will surely complain about it.

However, after testing part of your code, it returned `1431475200`, being an integer. So you may not need to quote it, but make sure your `date` column is an `int` type. Otherwise, you will need to quote the variable.

Doing `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` would have triggered a syntax error about `&today_time`.

---

If you want to use date/time, it's best to use MySQL's date time functions.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Otherwise, you may end up doing more work later on when querying.

- [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) is equivalent to what you're using now and is more effecient to use.

> Returns the current date as a value in **'YYYY-MM-DD'** or **YYYYMMDD** format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

- [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)  is also another function you can use.

> Returns the current date and time as a value in **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'** or **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu** format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

---

If your `date` column is a `DATE` type, then you only need to use `$today = date("Y-m-d");`.

You will then need to quote the `$today` variable.

```
where date = '$today'
```

Using `$today_time = strtotime($today);` will convert `2015-05-13` to `1431475200`, so I'm doubting that's what you want to use. Only you know what type the `date` column is.

From the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Comment: just an alternative, the OP could also use `CURDATE()`, but this answer should cover the problems